# Which LDAP Realm Should I Use When I have to Suport Multiple LDAP Implementations?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, shiro

I have a requirement for my (on-site installed web based) application to authenticate via LDAP and I am attempting to use Apache Shiro to do so.

The majority of my clients have Microsoft Active Directory, however, a couple have [Oracle Internet Directory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/overview/index-082035.html) or [Oracle Virtual Directory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/index-093158.html) and I think someone mentioned OpenLDAP.

I'm guessing, based on the name, that the ActiveDirectoryRealm only works with Microsoft ActiveDirectory. Is that right?

ActiveDirectoryRealm extends from AbstractLdapRealm and not from DefaultLdapRealm. However, DefaultLdapRealm extends from AuthorizingRealm and not AbstractLdapRealm, which is confusing and I'm not sure what I should be using.

Should I just give instructions to each client to change the shiro.ini depending on their LDAP implementation?

I would rather just have one implementation that I could use for all clients though and not bother them with low level config like this.

I will probably have to make a custom Realm to handle [other issues with Shiro](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-586). Am I going to have to make the same changes in 2 Realms - one for ActiveDirectory and one for other LDAP?

Or do I make one that extends DefaultLdapRealm and have to re-implement the code in the ActiveDirectoryRealm that searches for roles?

Answer (score 0):

Related questions have been posted in a few different places:
So for future Googlers:

http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Anonymous-binding-issue-while-searching-LDAP-roles-tp7581241p7581292.html

https://github.com/opticyclic/shiro-spring-examples/tree/master/ms-active-directory-custom

http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/New-LDAP-Realm-Proposal-tc7581200.html